# Deserialize XML to List<T> with XmlRootAttribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have a class called Car, with a property called LicencePlate,
when I serialize a List with XmlRootAttribute Cars, the XML created is

```
<Cars>
<Car>
 <LicencePlate></LicencePlate>
</Car>
<Cars>
```

the code to serialize it is

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(ListCars.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("Cars"));
```

but when i will deserialize this XML occur an error, because the class doesn't have 'Cars' attribute.

someone can help me?

Comment: Do you use the same code for deserializing?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, do it properly:

```
[XmlRoot("Cars"), XmlType("Cars")]
public class SomeWrapper {
    [XmlElement("Car")]
    public List<Car> Cars { get { return cars; } }
    private readonly List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
}
```

This wrapper should know to serialize/deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The Car Class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string LicencePlate { get; set; }
}
```

Your XML Class:

```
[XmlRoot("Cars")]
public class ListCars
{
    [XmlElement("Car")]
    public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to deserialize the object using the same XmlSerializer that you used to serialize it. Normally you would specify the XML structure in the class itself, using the [`XmlElementAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) and related XML serialization attributes.

If, for some reason, you do need to override the root element when you serialize the object, you need to override the root element going the other direction.

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
LoadSerializedObjectIntoTheStream(output);

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListCars), new XmlRootAttribute("Cars"));
var carlist = ser.Deserialize(output) as ListCars;
```

Comment: but the xml is not generated by me, who will generate it doesn't know the tag name, so I want to know a easy way to change this tag name

Comment: can you just open the XML as an XML document and read the name of the root tag?